# Fix a furniture on the ground created on a button using ARCore

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to a furniture app using ARCore, then click on a button to create a new model and put on fix position on the ground. The main issue is the model is following me when I move from point to point:

I tried to create anchor and put it on the ground but it's not working:

```
public void DuplicateObject()
{ 
    GameObject Cloud = GameObject.Find("Point Cloud");  
    //Vector3 CameraPosition = new Vector3(MainCamera.transform.position.x , 0 , MainCamera.transform.position.z + distance);
    Vector3 CameraPosition = new Vector3(MainCamera.transform.position.x, Cloud.transform.position.y , MainCamera.transform.position.z + distance );

    NewObject = GameObject.Instantiate(Gobject , transform.position , Quaternion.identity);
    NewObject.transform.position = MainCamera.transform.position + MainCamera.transform.forward * distance;

    Vector3 AnchorPos =  NewObject.transform.position;
    Pose pose = new Pose(AnchorPos, NewObject.transform.rotation);
    _anchor = Session.CreateAnchor(pose , null);
    //NewObject.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0, Space.Self);
    NewObject.transform.Rotate(0, k_ModelRotation,0 , Space.Self);
    _anchor.transform.parent = Cloud.transform;
    NewObject.transform.parent = _anchor.transform;
}
```

What I want to do is just fix the model in a specific position on the ground.  What's the correct (best) way to do that?